# Why the image in pygame doesn't remove but stops moving?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making an exercise from python crash course book and I want raindrops to dissapear(remove) after they hit the bottom of the screen. Instead of dissapearing they stop moving. When I write the same code (the removing part) in other similar project it works. This is the part of the code that is not working like I want it to.

```
import pygame
from settings import Settings
import sys
from raindrop import Image
from pygame.sprite import Sprite


class Raindrop(Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        
        # Initialize pygame and create screen
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
            [self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height])
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg)

        # Create group of raindrops
        self.raindrop = Image(self)
        self.raindrops = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.raindrops.add(self.raindrop)
        self.row_of_raindrops()

    def run_game(self):
        
        while True:
            self.not_quit()
            self._update_raindrop()
            self.update_screen()

            for drop in self.raindrops.copy():
                if drop.rect.bottom >= 750:
                    self.raindrops.remove(drop)

    def not_quit(self):
        # Not close the pygame window
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT or (
                event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_q):
                sys.exit()

    def row_of_raindrops(self):
        raindrop = Image(self)
        raindrop_width, raindrop_height = raindrop.rect.size
        width_for_raidnrops = self.settings.screen_width - (2 * raindrop_width)
        range_for_raindrops = width_for_raidnrops // (2 * raindrop_width)
        raindrop_width, raindrop_height = raindrop.rect.size
        height_for_raindrops = self.settings.screen_height - (3 * raindrop_height)
        range_height_for_raindrops = height_for_raindrops // (2 * raindrop_height)
        for raindrop_number in range(range_for_raindrops):
            for column_numbers in range(range_height_for_raindrops):
                raindrop = Image(self)
                raindrop.x = raindrop_width + 2 * raindrop_width * raindrop_number
                raindrop.rect.x = raindrop.x
                raindrop.y = raindrop_height + 2 * raindrop_height * column_numbers
                raindrop.rect.y = raindrop.y
                self.raindrops.add(raindrop)
    
    def _update_raindrop(self):
        self.raindrops.update()


    def update_screen(self):
        self.raindrops.draw(self.screen)
        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = Raindrop()
    x.run_game()



import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Image(Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x_game):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.screen = x_game.screen
        self.settings = x_game.settings

        # Load image and get it rect
        self.image = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/lukas/Desktop/python/raindrops/raindrop.jpg")
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (50, 50))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # Raindrop position
        self.rect.x = self.rect.width
        self.rect.y = self.rect.height

        self.y = float(self.rect.y)

    def update(self):
        self.y += self.settings.raindrop_speed
        self.rect.y = self.y
```

Comment: This code works fine, except that `self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg)` is missing in `update_screen`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scene is redrawn in every frame. Therefore you need to clear the display in the application loop:

```py
class Raindrop(Sprite):
    # [...]

    def update_screen(self):
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg)
        self.raindrops.draw(self.screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
```

You need to call [`kill`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill) to remove *Sprites*. `kill()` remove the Sprite from all Groups and you can call this method while iterating through the *Group*.

Additionally use [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) to control the frames per second and thus the game speed.

The method [`tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) of a [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) object, delays the game in that way, that every iteration of the loop consumes the same period of time. See [`pygame.time.Clock.tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick):

> This method should be called once per frame.

```py
class Raindrop(Sprite):
    # [...]

    def run_game(self):

        clock = pygame.time.Clock()        
        while True:
            clock.tick(100)

            self.not_quit()
            self._update_raindrop()
            self.update_screen()

            for drop in self.raindrops:
                if drop.rect.bottom >= self.settings.screen_height:
                    drop.kill()
```